# Does stacking power armors work?

Tags: mass-effect-3

At the moment I am playing as a Sentinel which has the Tech Armor power, I also took Fortification as my secondary power. But the question i have is do both of these actually stack? Or does one damage reduction just nullify the other?

The second part on this question is if they do stack, both powers say Slows down power use. But with both of them active would that mean it double slows, thus also stacking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Stacking Tech Armor with Fortification or Defense Matrix will work.

It will stack the cooldown penalty also, but if it makes you a walking tank, I guess it's worth it!

http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Tech_Armor#Player_Notes_2